# Android, Google Maps API, JSON issues. Getting a null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I'm working on a small personnel app to help me learn Android dev and Java.

Let me start this by letting everyone know that Google Maps part is working in the app. It is loading when the app starts and gets the correct current location of the phone.

Also, my JSON stuff is working as well. The data is being pulled from www.wunderground.com using their API, my code grabs what I'm asking for and creates an Arraylist and populates it just fine and displays that in the app as it should.

The problem is, i'm trying to get a couple pieces of JSON data, and create a google map Marker object and display that on the map.

Below is my code:

This method is creating a Cyclone Object from the JSON data it gets from JsonData.java, which I show below.

**Cyclone.java**

```
public class Cyclone {

// Category of the cyclone (e.g. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5)
private int category;

// Latitude & Longitude of Cyclone
private float latitude, longitude;

// Cyclone name
private String name;

// Cyclone heading (N, S, E, or W)
private String heading;

// Wind speed in Cyclone
private String windSpeedKnots;

// Url to website with Cyclone data
private String url;

/**
* CONSTRUCTOR
* Create a new Cyclone object.
*
* @param constCategory is the category of the cyclone (e.g. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5)
* @param constLatitude is the Latitude of the cyclone
* @param constLongitude is the Longitude of the cyclone
* @param constName is the name of the Cyclone
* @param constHeading is the direction the cyclone is moving
* @param constWindSpeedKnots is the speed of the wind the Cyclone is producing
* @param constUrl is the url of the website that is providing the data
*/
public Cyclone(int constCategory, float constLatitude, float constLongitude,String constName,
               String constHeading, String constWindSpeedKnots, String constUrl) {

    category = constCategory;
    latitude = constLatitude;
    longitude = constLongitude;
    name = constName;
    heading = constHeading;
    windSpeedKnots = constWindSpeedKnots;
    url = constUrl;
}

/**
 * Setting public getters for the private variables above for use of other classes
 */
// Get the storm category
public int getCategory() {
    return category;
}

// Get the cyclones Latitude
public float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

//Get the cyclones Longitude
public float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

// Get the cyclones name
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

// Get the cyclones heading
public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

// Get the cyclones wind speed
public String getWindSpeedKnots() {
    return windSpeedKnots;
}

// Get the Url
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
```

}

This class pulls the JSON Data from www.wunderground.com. I've cut off a bunch code from the bottom. It is mostly just handling exceptions if nothing is returned.
**JsonData.java**

```
/**
 * Return a list of {@link Cyclone} objects that has been built up from
 * parsing a JSON response.
 */
public static ArrayList<Cyclone> extractFeatureFromJson(String cycloneJSON) {

    // Create an empty ArrayList to start adding Cyclones to
    ArrayList<Cyclone> cyclones = new ArrayList<>();

    // Try to parse the cycloneJSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
    // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
    // Catch the exception , and print the error message to the logs.

    try {

        JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(cycloneJSON);

        // Create JSONArray associated with the key called "currenthurricane", which represents
        // a list of cyclones from JSON response.
        JSONArray currentHurricaneArray = rootJsonObject.getJSONArray("currenthurricane");

        /**
         * Loop through each section in the currentHurricaneArray array & create an
         * {@link Cyclone} object for each one
         *
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < currentHurricaneArray.length(); i++) {
            //Get cyclone JSONObject at position i in the array
            JSONObject cycloneProperties = currentHurricaneArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // Extract "stormInfo" object
            JSONObject stormInfo = cycloneProperties.optJSONObject("stormInfo");
            //Extract “stormName_Nice” & "requesturl" for Cyclone's name and url
            String name = stormInfo.optString("stormName_Nice");
            String url = stormInfo.optString("wuiurl");

            // Extract "Current" object
            JSONObject current = cycloneProperties.optJSONObject("Current");
            // Extract "SaffirSimpsonCategory" key
            int category = current.optInt("SaffirSimpsonCategory");

            //Extract "Lat" & "Lon" keys to get cyclone position
            float latitude = (float) current.optDouble("lat");
            float longitude = (float) current.optDouble("lon");

            //Extract "WindSpeed" object
            JSONObject windSpeed = current.optJSONObject("WindSpeed");
            //Extract wind speed in "Knots" Key
            int Kts = windSpeed.optInt("Kts");
            String knots = Kts + " Knots";

            //Extract "Movement" object
            JSONObject movement = current.optJSONObject("Movement");
            //Extract movement direction in "Text" key
            String direction = movement.optString("Text");

            Cyclone cyclone = new Cyclone(category, latitude, longitude, name, direction, knots, url);
            //Add new cyclone to list
            cyclones.add(cyclone);
        }
```

I'll just show the relevant bits here.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Cyclone>>,
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

....

//Creating a Cyclone object, calling it from Cyclone.java
    Cyclone trackedCyclone = null;

    //getting the three bits of info I need/want (Name, lat, lon)
    String name = trackedCyclone.getName();
    float lat = trackedCyclone.getLatitude();
    float lon = trackedCyclone.getLongitude();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cyclone_list);
....

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready
    //Calling up the map fragment from cyclone_list.xml
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

....

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mapLocalInstance) {
    //Setting mapReady to true
    mapReady = true;

    //displaying cyclone map marker on the map
    LatLng cycloneMarker = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cycloneMarker).title(name));

    //Loading local instance map from Callback
    googleMap = mapLocalInstance;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    //checks for permission using the Support library before enabling the My Location layer
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

When the app is started, it crashes with the following:

> 04-17 16:11:29.546 7028-7028/com.palarran.cycloops E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.palarran.cycloops, PID: 7028
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.palarran.cycloops.Cyclone.getName()' on a null object reference
>                                                                            at com.palarran.cycloops.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:266)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
>                                                                            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1805)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

I've only been messing about with Android and Java for about a year. So OOP is still pretty new to me. I don't understand a lot of it. I sorta half think the issue is that since that **JsonData.java** class is creating an JsonArray, I may not be able to just call the parts I need out using the **Cyclone.java** class. If that is the case, then do I create different JsonArray? That seems clunky to me? But I really don't know.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `Cyclone trackedCyclone = null;` does not create a `Cyclone` object, as the comment above the respective line states. The following line crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Creating a Cyclone object, calling it from Cyclone.java
Cyclone trackedCyclone = null;

// Here is a problem. You need to init your trackedCyclone
trackedCyclone = new Cyclone(??????????);

//getting the three bits of info I need/want (Name, lat, lon)
String name = trackedCyclone.getName();
float lat = trackedCyclone.getLatitude();
float lon = trackedCyclone.getLongitude();
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me immensely. First, I was not instantiating. Not excuse there. Second: after I corrected this, I realized a HUGE misunderstanding i've been under for a while. For some reason, I have believed that a class could ONLY have ONE constructor! It has made my code so odd. I do not know why I have thought this to be true.